# How do I determine the maximum RAM installable in a Dell Inspiron 15R SE?

Tags: laptop, memory, dell-inspiron, memory-limit

I'm looking for a new laptop and the [Dell Inspiron 15R SE](http://www.dell.com/uk/p/inspiron-15r-se-7520/fs) seems a pretty good fit for my requirements. However, I can't find the maximum RAM capacity anywhere in the spec. It seems Dell don't ship them with any more than 8GB, but how can I tell what I can extend that to after sale? I'm looking at the model with an Intel i7 3612QM which [has a max memory size of 32GB](http://ark.intel.com/products/64901) ("dependent on memory type"). But I don't know enough to be sure if that's the only limiting factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kingston reports the [largest available module as 4GB](http://www.kingston.com/us/memory/search?DeviceType=3&Mfr=DEL&Line=Inspiron&Model=63971).  With 2 banks this makes the maximum 8GB.  Generally I have found Kingston to be quite reliable.

Comment: Agreed...  http://www.crucial.com is also pretty good

Comment: Thanks guys. I always use Offtek and they also [show 4GB as the maximum module available](http://www.offtek.co.uk/ram-memory-2/dell/dell-laptop-memory/inspiron-15r/mid145322).